# Наследование Activity. Передача данных из Thread в Activity через Message

Tags: android, многопоточность, activity

Есть класс, от которого будут наследоваться другие классы:

```
public class ActivityUART extends Activity {
protected Handler handlerUART;
private byte[] cmdBuffer;

private class ReadThread extends Thread {
@Override
public void run() {
super.run();
cmdBuffer = new byte[13];
while(!isInterrupted()) {
// cmdBuffer[cntCmdByte] - заполняем буфер
Message msg = null;
msg = handlerUART.obtainMessage(cmdBuffer.length, cmdBuffer);
handlerUART.sendMessage(msg);
}
}
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
mReadThread = new ReadThread();
mReadThread.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
if (mReadThread != null)
mReadThread.interrupt();
super.onPause();
}
```

Первый класс:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActivityUART {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
handlerUART = new Handler() {
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
super.handleMessage(msg);

byte[] buffer = new byte[msg.what];
buffer = (byte[]) msg.obj;

if (buffer[4] == 5) {
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, timeActivity.class));
}
};
super.onResume();
@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
}
```

Второй класс:

```
public class timeActivity extends ActivityUART {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.newactivity);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

handlerUART = new Handler() {
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
super.handleMessage(msg);
byte[] buffer = new byte[msg.what];
buffer = (byte[]) msg.obj;

if (buffer[4] == 5) {
Log.d(TAG, "execute key OK");
}
};

super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
}
```

А теперь вопрос:

При первой передаче данных от `ReadThread` к `MainActivity` все происходит, как и должно быть, запускается `timeActivity`. Но при следующей передаче данных уже от `ReadThread` к `timeActivity` не происходит `Log.d(TAG, "execute key OK");`, а вместо этого еще раз запускается `timeActivity`. Если еще раз передавать данные от `ReadThread` к `timeActivity`, то будет выполнятся строка `Log.d(TAG, "execute key OK");`. Но если аппаратной кнопкой андроида "назад" закрыть созданные `timeActivity`, вернуться к `MainActivity` и передать данные опять от `ReadThread` к `MainActivity`, то по-прежнему будет выполняться строка `Log.d(TAG, "execute key OK");` вместо строки `startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, timeActivity.class));`.

Почему так происходит? И как мне обратится именно к обработчику сообщений текущей Activity?

Comment: Все, разобрался в родительском классе ActivityUART хендлер handlerUART нужно описать как static protected, и все будет работать.

Comment: чуть с ума не сошел :)

Comment: @selya, вы бы оформили ваше решение в виде ответа и приняли бы его. Так, в будущем, если кто-то с этим столкнётся, то это поможет емуу решить проблему.

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ У меня не хватало очков репутации для ответа на свой вопрос. По этому я и написал в комментариях

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хандлер  handlerUART в родительском классе описать как `protected Handler handlerUART;`, то при передачи сообщения из потока не всегда будет обрабатываться текущей Activity, хоть и сам хандлер создается именно в этой Activity `handlerUART = new Handler() {`.Если я правильно понял, то если описать хандлер как он описан выше, то ссылка на этот хандлер будет зависеть от активностей, которые все еще находятся в памяти (у меня было даже такое, что сообщение из потока обрабатывал `public void handleMessage(Message msg)` вообще из другой программы). Для того что бы получить прямую ссылке на хандлер, его необходимо описать в родительском классе как `static protected Handler handlerUART;`. И тогда все работает так как надо. Может быть эта проблема имеет еще решения, но я их не нашел. Если кто о них знает, большая просьба - напишите!!!